# Does command substitution within arithmetic substitution get word split?

Tags: bash, arithmetic, words

I seem to recall from comments on this site that the contents of arithmetic expansion **may** be word split, but I can't find the comment again.

Consider the following code:

```
printf '%d\n' "$(($(sed -n '/my regex/{=;q;}' myfile)-1))"
```

If the `sed` command outputs a multi-digit number and `$IFS` contains digits, will the command substitution get word split before the arithmetic occurs?

(I've already tested using extra double quotes:

```
printf '%d\n' "$(("$(sed -n '/my regex/{=;q;}' myfile)"-1))"
```

and this doesn't work.)

---

Incidentally the example code above is a reduced-to-simplest-form alteration of [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35882480/5419599) that I just posted on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

In `$((expression))`, *expression* is treated as it was in double quote, as [POSIX specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04).

But beware that the expression inside command substitution still be subjected to `split+glob`:

```
$ printf '%d\n' "$(( $(IFS=0; a=10; echo $a) + 1 ))"
2
```

With double quote:

```
$ printf '%d\n' "$(( $(IFS=0; a=10; echo "$a") + 1 ))"
11
```

---

Like other expansions, arithmetic expansion, if not inside double quote, undergo `split+glob`:

```
$ IFS=0
$ echo $((10))
1
```

Comment: Thanks...if you find the conversation in comments I'm recalling, I'd love to see a link to it.  It was a conversation between mikeserv and Stephane.

Comment: To ensure I've got it correctly, if the arithmetic expansion itself isn't double quoted, THEN it can be split—is that correct?

Comment: @Wildcard: Yes, see my editing.

Answer (score 2):

From bash manual (run `LESS=+/'^ *Arithmetic Expansion' man bash` ):

> Arithmetic Expansion
>
> All tokens in the  expression  undergo  parameter expansion, string expansion, command substitution, and quote removal.

So, no no splitting is performed.

Comment: @cuonglm That is an answer to what was not asked.